# Adding additional details to principal object stored in spring security context

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I am using Spring 3.0 and Spring Security 3. I am able to authenticate a user against a database using Spring Security. Using:

```
SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal()
```

I am able to retrieve username of the current logged in user. I wish to add additional details like user id and the module accesses to the principal object stored in Spring Security context so that I can retrieve it later. How can I add additional details to the principal object and then how can I retrieve it later on a jsp or java class. Please provide an appropriate code snippet if possible.

Edit: I am using JDBC to access my database.

Comment: Creating your own `UserDetails` implementation and your own `UserDetailsService` implementation. With that you can do whatever you want. Add the properties you want etc.

Comment: Thanks. I have been trying to do the same but I think I am doing something wrong. @M.Deinum Could you please provide me a code snippet where this has been successfully implemented

Answer (score 32, accepted):

In order to add more details to the authenticated user. You need to first create your own implementation of the User object which should extend the spring security User object. After that you can add the properties you want to add to the authenticated user. Once this is done you need to return your implementation of the user object in `UserDetailService` (If you are not using LDAP for authentication). This link provides the details for adding more details to the authenticated user--

http://javahotpot.blogspot.com/2013/12/spring-security-adding-more-information.html

Comment: Could you also post the implementation of loadUserDetails(username) in LoginService of the example link. I want to know how the failed authentication requests will be handled. Thanks in advance

Comment: Answered at the mentioned link only..http://javahotpot.blogspot.in/2013/12/spring-security-adding-more-information.html

Comment: Your link to your blog doesn't fully answer the question, as was asked for the implantation of LoginService.  Typically you should answer the question on this site, not reference a post on your blog.

Comment: Why you said **If you are not using LDAP for authentication** ? Will this solution not work with LDAP?

Comment: because with this service you need to return the password to spring, and you cannot read password from LDAP.. instead, to use LDAP you can implement a AuthenticationProvider

Comment: This answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/41327161/7886278 on this same question is much more helpful :)

Answer (score 37):

Here is what you need:

1. Extend spring `User` (`org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User`) class and what ever properties you need.
2. Extend spring `UserDetailsService` (`org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService`) and fill the above object. Override `loadUserByUsername` and return your extended user class
3. Set your custom `UserDetailsService` in `AuthenticationManagerBuilder`

For example

```
public class CurrentUser extends User{

   //This constructor is a must
    public CurrentUser(String username, String password, boolean enabled, boolean accountNonExpired,
            boolean credentialsNonExpired, boolean accountNonLocked,
            Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> authorities) {
        super(username, password, enabled, accountNonExpired, credentialsNonExpired, accountNonLocked, authorities);
    }
    //Setter and getters are required
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;

}
```

The Custom userdetails could be:

```
@Service("userDetailsService")
public class CustomUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {

@Override
public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(final String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {

    //Try to find user and its roles, for example here we try to get it from database via a DAO object
   //Do not confuse this foo.bar.User with CurrentUser or spring User, this is a temporary object which holds user info stored in database
    foo.bar.User user = userDao.findByUserName(username);

    //Build user Authority. some how a convert from your custom roles which are in database to spring GrantedAuthority
    List<GrantedAuthority> authorities = buildUserAuthority(user.getUserRole());

    //The magic is happen in this private method !
    return buildUserForAuthentication(user, authorities);

}


//Fill your extended User object (CurrentUser) here and return it
private User buildUserForAuthentication(foo.bar.User user, 
List<GrantedAuthority> authorities) {
    String username = user.getUsername();
    String password = user.getPassword();
    boolean enabled = true;
    boolean accountNonExpired = true;
    boolean credentialsNonExpired = true;
    boolean accountNonLocked = true;

    return new CurrentUser(username, password, enabled, accountNonExpired, credentialsNonExpired,
            accountNonLocked, authorities);
   //If your database has more information of user for example firstname,... You can fill it here 
  //CurrentUser currentUser = new CurrentUser(....)
  //currentUser.setFirstName( user.getfirstName() );
  //.....
  //return currentUser ;
}

private List<GrantedAuthority> buildUserAuthority(Set<UserRole> userRoles) {

    Set<GrantedAuthority> setAuths = new HashSet<GrantedAuthority>();

    // Build user's authorities
    for (UserRole userRole : userRoles) {
        setAuths.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(userRole.getRole()));
    }

    return new ArrayList<GrantedAuthority>(setAuths);
}

}
```

Configure the spring security context

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@PropertySource("classpath://configs.properties")
public class SecurityContextConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("userDetailsService")
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService);
    }
```

It's all done !

You can call `(CurrentUser)getAuthentication().getPrincipal()` to get you newly `CurrentUser` or set some properties.

Comment: This works, but when the server restarts, we run into problems with existing sessions: java.lang.ClassCastException: be.storefront.imicloud.security.MyUserDetails cannot be cast to be.storefront.imicloud.security.MyUserDetails. How should this be handled?

Comment: @Wouter please ask a different question with the full stack trace!

Comment: Solution is nice but make sure you don't cast `(CurrentUser)getAuthentication().getPrincipal()` into the controller/service methods which are accessible without authentication. Because for that `anonymous` would be returned by `getAuthentication().getPrincipal()` and hence `ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to com.sample.CurrentUser`

Comment: I found this dangerous when you directly change the other parameters on DBs like the parameter above "firstname", the persistence framework still shows the previous value....

Comment: @Wouter For the example above, The casting exception occurs when the properties on "//Setter and getters are required"  and the ones on " //If your database has more information of user for example firstname,... You can fill it here " are not in accordance.

Comment: I had to do a couple of additional changes to get things in place but they were specific to my use case & this is a good reference to achieve custom user details in spring security. I tried it with jwt :) & this helped!

Answer (score 14):

(I will assume you have a basic Spring Security configuration working and know how the basic components work together)

The most "correct" way would be providing your own implementation of [`AuthenticationProvider`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/authentication/AuthenticationProvider.html), that return a custom [`Authentication`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/core/Authentication.html) implementation. Then you can fill in this `Authentication` instance with everything you need. For example:

```
public class MyAuthentication extends UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken implements Authentication {

    public MyAuthentication(Object principal, Object credentials, int moduleCode) {
        super(principal, credentials);
        this.moduleCode = moduleCode;
    }

    public MyAuthentication(Object principal, Object credentials,  Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> authorities,int moduleCode) {
        super(principal, credentials, authorities);
        this.moduleCode = moduleCode;
    }

    private int moduleCode;

    public getModuleCode() {
        return moduleCode;
    }   
}


public class MyAuthenticationProvider extends DaoAuthenticationProvider {

    private Collection<GrantedAuthority> obtainAuthorities(UserDetails user) {
        // return granted authorities for user, according to your requirements
    }

    private int obtainModuleCode(UserDetails user) {
        // return moduleCode for user, according to your requirements
    }

    @Override
    public Authentication createSuccessAuthentication(Object principal, Authentication authentication, UserDetails user) {
        // Suppose this user implementation has a moduleCode property
        MyAuthentication result = new MyAuthentication(authentication.getPrincipal(),
                                                       authentication.getCredentials(),
                                                       obtainAuthorities(user),
                                                       obtainModuleCode(user));
        result.setDetails(authentication.getDetails());
        return result;
    }
}
```

And then, in `applicationContext.xml`:

```
<authentication-manager>
    <authentication-provider ref="myAuthenticationProvider">
</authentication-manager>

<bean id="myAuthenticationProvider" class="MyAuthenticationProvider" scope="singleton">
    ...
</bean>
```

I guess you could get it working by providing custom implementations of [`AuthenticationDetails`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/authentication/AuthenticationDetails.html) and [`AuthenticationDetailsSource`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/authentication/AuthenticationDetailsSource.html), but I think that would be a less clean approach.

Answer (score 5):

The "only" things you need to do is create your own [UserDetailsService](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.4.RELEASE/reference/technical-overview.html#tech-userdetailsservice) implementation which returns your own implementation of a [UserDetails](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.4.RELEASE/reference/technical-overview.html#tech-userdetailsservice) object.

See [here](http://krams915.blogspot.nl/2012/01/spring-security-31-implement_5023.html) for a tutorial which implements a JPA based `UserDetailsService`.

Comment: I am using JDBC to connect to the database. Can you specify the changes I would have to make in the tutorial since it is JPA based.

Comment: I am not sure on how to handle failed authentication requests with JDBC when I override the loadUserByUsername(String username) of UserDetailsService. Could you help me with that.

Comment: Why would you need to handle failed authentication requests? Spring does that for you and that doesn't change when you implement your own `UserDetailsService`.

Comment: Take for example the scenario when username and password do not match, how should I handle that when I override the method. Should I just return a null object in that case?

Comment: You don't handle that, spring security handles that for you. The `UserDetailsService` is **ONLY** for looking up users NOT for checking the password. As you noticed there is only a method `loadUserByUsername` the name of the method says it all, the same for the attributes of the method, there is no password so how would you validate the password?!

Comment: When is the method `loadUserByUsername` called in the authentication process and how will the authentication happen when I create custom implementations of `UserDetails` and `UserDetailsService`. Pardon my lack of knowledge as I am fairly new to Spring

Comment: Spring Security calls the method and afterwards, depending on your configuration, checks the password. The authentication doesn't change, nothing changes **ONLY** where/how you get your user info. As long as it is a `UserDetails` implementation nothing changes.

Comment: Thanks M. Deinum, I got it and I am able to add information to the user.