# Spring: Save Logged In User Session

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-mvc, authentication

I don't understand where the current logged in user is saved in the application. I want to save the user (after his login) in my spring application. I use Spring Security and already read about the `SecurityContextHolder` but the problem is I have a custom user class, which is saved in a mongodb. I could query the user from the database after login (check the password and so on), but what are the next steps?

Greetings Chryb

EDIT:

My bigger question is how I should combine my user repository with my login?

EDIT:

Look at my other question for more details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26674438/spring-xml-config-dont-work)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Adding additional details to principal object stored in spring security context](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20349594/adding-additional-details-to-principal-object-stored-in-spring-security-context)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I have it! This [guide](http://www.jroller.com/jbrosan/entry/spring_security_and_mongodb) was a good help. The extra point is to write

```
@Override
public void init(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.userDetailsService(mongoSecurityService);
}
```

if you don't use .xml configuration. I have special thanks to guys who don't help answer the question and only flame the post like RC.

Comment: This link redirects to some casino website