# Validate the user in the resource server spring security

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

I have a Authorization server and a resource server implemented using spring boot with oauth2. 
In the resource server I have configured the check_token endpoint and relevant information to validate the requests from authorization server.

```
security:
  oauth2:
    resource:
      token-info-uri: http://localhost:9191/auth-service/oauth/check_token
    client:
      client-id: mobile
      client-secret: secret
```

So now when a request is comes with a bearer token it allows to access the resource server. But if a token is stolen and try to update a record of a another user it is still possible since he/she has a valid token. To reduce this risk i wanted to add a filter in the resource server and check with the unique id which comes with the request header against the id field that i have added to token when a token is generated. But the authentication object only returns the username of the owner of the token.

```java
final OAuth2Authentication authentication = (OAuth2Authentication) SecurityContextHolder
            .getContext().getAuthentication();

// this principal object returns the user name.
Object principal = authentication.getUserAuthentication().getPrincipal();
```

I want this principal object or another property to send me the userid which i set to the token.This is my check_token response, as you can see it has the userid field in the response.

```
{
  "aud": [
    "oauth2-resource"
  ],
  "data": {
    "userId": "uid-0c51148d-162a-4fa4-95c5-asd3434",
  },
  "user_name": "test",
  "scope": [
    "READ",
    "WRITE",
    "UPDATE"
  ],
  "active": true,
  "client_id": "mobile",
}
```

Please help me to sort this out.

Comment: why dont you just add the users id in the database to the userdetails object (principal) so that when a request comes in, resource server fetches and populates the principal. uou get the id from the principal and then use that to update the user object. Then each token can only update one single user.

Comment: @ThomasAndolf are you suggesting to set the user_id instead of username right ?

Comment: no, im suggestion that you in your authorization server implement a custom userdetails object. when your resource server fetches the principal, it will get that custom userdetail object, but when you then get your principal in the resource server, you need to cast it to your custom userdetail object.

Comment: the token has no information. A user token is just a string. Your resource server gets the token, send it you your authorization server, authorization service validates it, and then returns the userdetails object. You can define your own custom userdetails object and return whatever you want.

Comment: if you dont understand what im talking about, i suggest you read spring security documentation about how spring security works and what the userdetails object is etc. etc. https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#overall-architecture

Comment: @ThomasAndolf Thank you for your suggestions, I am trying to do this customization as you mentioned, will let you know the progress.

Comment: @ThomasAndolf I need to clarity few things, when you say "your resource serve fetches the principal" do you mean that it's fetch through a controller or the SecurityContextHolder as I mentioned in the question. Because I have a custom userdetails object which implements the userdetails object and still the authentication.getUserAuthentication().getPrincipal(); returns only the username.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207894/discussion-between-rajith-k-and-thomas-andolf).