# Display user details in jsp using spring security

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, jsp, spring-boot, spring-security

I have implemented an app in spring boot with spring security. I need to display **User's firstname, lastname and the image path in jsp page *(which is used for header, it means globally available even if we navigate to another URL*) after successfully logged in**. I'm using `remember-me` using `PersistentLogin`. So I can't use session to store details. Because If I close the browser, session will be destroyed.

I have implemented `CustomUserDetailsService`, it returns `org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User`

```
@Service("customUserDetailsService")
public class CustomUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService{
    //codes
    return new org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User(
        username,
        password,
        enabled,
        accountNonExpired,
        credentialsNonExpired,
        accountNonLocked,
        authorities);
}
```

I know there are two limitaions

> - If I don't use remember-me, I can easily store within session.
> - If I return `User` model class in `CustomUserDetailsService ...`,I can easily get user details in jsp
>     page using`<security:authentication property="principal.firstName">`
>     tag in jsp. But I need to return `org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User`

Unfortunately I need both limitation. My `User` model class has `firstName, lastName, imagePath,.. etc.`

How can I display user details in jsp page? Any approaches available? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring inbuilt provides the solution to do the same.

Java code :

```
public User getCurrentUser() {
        Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
        if (auth != null) {
            Object principal = auth.getPrincipal();
            if (principal instanceof User) {
                return ((User) principal);
            }
        }

    }
```

JSP code :

```
${pageContext["request"].userPrincipal.principal}
```

Comment: You can create one util class and use that wherever you want to get loggedin user details.

Comment: see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20349594/adding-additional-details-to-principal-object-stored-in-spring-security-context

Comment: Im sorry, I used that jsp page for header. So once I successfully authenticated, I need to display it, even if I navigate to another page also, header will be there.

Comment: yes in header jsp page you use ${pageContext["request"].userPrincipal.principal} to get details.

Answer (score 0):

HWat i have done is, I created a prototype of `User` called `UserAuth`

```
public class UserAuth extends org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User{
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String imagePath;

    public UserAuth(String username, String password, boolean enabled,
            boolean accountNonExpired, boolean credentialsNonExpired,
            boolean accountNonLocked, Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> authorities,
             String firstName, String lastName, String imagePath) {

                 super(username, password, enabled, accountNonExpired,
                    credentialsNonExpired, accountNonLocked, authorities);

                 this.firstName = firstName;
                 this.lastName = lastName;
                 this.imagePath = imagePath;
         }

    //getters and setters   

}
```

In CustomeUserDetailsService

```
@Service("customUserDetailsService")
public class CustomUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService{
    //codes
    return UserAuth
        username,
        password,
        enabled,
        accountNonExpired,
        credentialsNonExpired,
        accountNonLocked,
        authorities,
        user.getFirstName(),
        user.getLastName(),
        user.getImagePath());
}
```