# Common shared data objects for entire application

Tags: spring-boot

I have some data objects that are common across a Spring boot application - one is the logged in `employee` object and other is a `category`. I have created a `@Component` class which contains these are static variables. This way I do not even have to autowire them. They can be used directly like `CurrentContext.employee` in controllers.

```
@Component
public final class CurrentContext {

public static Category currentCategory;
public static Employee employee;

@Autowired
private CategoryService categoryService;
@Autowired
private EmployeeService employeeService;

@EventListener
public void onApplicationEvent(ContextRefreshedEvent event) {
    currentCategory = categoryService.getCategory();
}

@EventListener
public void onLoginSuccess(InteractiveAuthenticationSuccessEvent event) {
    employee = employeeService.getEmployeeByUserId(((MyUserDetails) event.getAuthentication().getPrincipal()).getUserId());
}

}
```

Is this a right way? Please suggest if there is a better way to handle shared data

**Edit**
Some background - I require the current logged in `employee` and a `category` which is common for all employees. So I `autowired` `employeeService` and `categoryService` in my controllers and use them to get the data. They are required in almost all my controller methods, so, I wanted to create a bean of these so that I directly use them in my controller and also save frequent database calls.

Comment: `employee` should be different for each login user ? If yes and you do it in this way , then you always get the same employee .....

Comment: Agreed the comment. Do you develop a mono user application ?

Comment: As you have rightly mentioned Ken, this is a major fail for me as the same employee gets loaded for every user. David, this is a multi user application. So how can I fix it so that each user has their details loaded?

Answer (score 0):

Normally, we only put the dependencies related to the cross-cutting concerns (i.e dependencies that are across the whole application such as security , logging , transaction stuff , time provider etc.) in the static field.

By accessing these kind of dependencies in the static way , we don't need to pass them through method parameters /constructors from object to object , which will make the API much cleaner without such noise (BTW. This is called `Ambient Context Pattern` in the .NET world).

Your `Employee` object most probably belong to this type , so it is ok to access it in a static way. But as their scope is per session , you cannot simply put it in the static field of a class. If yes, then you always get the same employee for all sessions. Instead, you have to somehow store it in an object which is  session scope (e.g `HttpSession`) . Then at the beginning of handling a web request , you get it from the session and then put it in a `ThreadLocal` which is encapsulated inside a "ContextHolder" object. You then access that "ContextHolder" in a static way.

Sound very complicated and scary ? Don't worry as Spring Security has already implemented this stuff for you. What you need to do is to [customize `Authentication#getPrincipal()`or extend default `Authentication`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20349594/adding-additional-details-to-principal-object-stored-in-spring-security-context) to contain your `Employee`. Then get it using `SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication()`

For your `currentCategory` , if they are not the cross-cutting concerns and is the application scope , make a singleton bean to get it values is a much better OOP design.

```
@Component
public final class CurrentCategoryProvider {

    @Autowired
    private CategoryService categoryService;

    public Category getCurrentCategory(){
        //or cache the value to the an internal properties depending on your requirements
        return categoryService.getCategory();
    }

}
```

You then inject `CurrentCategoryProvider` to the bean that need to access `currentCategory`.

Comment: Thank you @ken-chan. If i try to get the `employee` from `SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication()` , I do not get the 'complete' object, it will contain proxy for other objects like `Project` which is part of employee. Eager fetch may resolve this, but I was thinking of a simpler solution. I was thinking if i can create an employee bean which will be trigger on authentication success event, it should be good. I have added some updates to my original question. Sorry, I am new to Spring.

Comment: Yes. You have to eager fetch all the  required object which is  very normal.Btw , if you create an employer bean on authentication success event , you are back to that questions.  Will each login user get back their own employee bean once they login ?