# Why all properties of a Model passed from AOP to controller with other arguments are null

Tags: spring, spring-aop

AOP

```java
@Around(
    "execution(* net.inter.warp.bridge.controller.*.*(.., net.inter.warp.bridge.model.User)) && " +
    "args(.., authenticatedUser)"
)
public Object withAuthenticatedUser(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint, User authenticatedUser) throws Throwable {
    System.out.println(joinPoint + " -> " + authenticatedUser);
    User user = null;
    Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
    if (authentication != null)
        user = (User) userService.loadUserByUsername(authentication.getName());
    else
        throw new UnauthorizedException("err 1");
    if (user == null)
        throw new UnauthorizedException("err 2");
    return joinPoint.proceed(new Object[]{user});
}
```

Controller (all properties of authenticatedUser are null)

```java
package net.inter.warp.bridge.controller;

@GetMapping("/boxes/{id}")
public ResponseEntity<Box> getBoxById(@PathVariable(value = "id") Long boxId, User authenticatedUser)
    throws NoDynamicTableFoundException, ResourceNotFoundException {}
```

Controller (This works as there is no more parameters except for  authenticatedUser)

```java
package net.inter.warp.bridge.controller;

@GetMapping("/boxes/{id}")
public ResponseEntity<Box> getBoxById(User authenticatedUser)
    throws NoDynamicTableFoundException, ResourceNotFoundException {}
```

AOP seems to hate other paramethers... authenticatedUser is not null, every property of authenticatedUser is null.

Model (I am not sure this issue is related to this)

```java
@Entity
@Table(name="users")
@ToString
public class User extends AuthEntity implements UserDetails
{
    @Override
    public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
        String[] userRoles = this.roles.stream().map((role) -> role.getName()).toArray(String[]::new);
        Collection<GrantedAuthority> authorities = AuthorityUtils.createAuthorityList(userRoles);
        return authorities;
    }

    @Override
    public String getUsername() {
        return this.email;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled() {
        return true;
    }

    @Column(nullable=false)
    @NotNull(message = "")
    private String name;

    @Column(nullable=false, unique=true)
    @Email
    //@NotBlank(message = "")
    private String email;

    @Column
    @JsonProperty(access = JsonProperty.Access.WRITE_ONLY)
    @JsonIgnore
    private String password;


    @Column(length = 20, columnDefinition ="bigint")
    //@NotNull(message = "")
    private Long organization_id;

    @ManyToOne(optional=false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "organization_id",referencedColumnName="id", insertable=false, updatable=false)
    //@JsonIgnore
    private Organization organization;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.MERGE)
    //@Fetch(org.hibernate.annotations.FetchMode.SELECT)
    @JoinTable(
            name="user_role",
            joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="user_id")},
            inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="role_id")})

    private List<Role> roles;

/*
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.MERGE)
    //@Fetch(org.hibernate.annotations.FetchMode.SELECT)
    @Fetch(value = FetchMode.SUBSELECT)
    @JoinTable(
            name="hyperbridge_resource.user_workspace",
            joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="user_id")},
            inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="workspace_id")})

    private List<Workspace> workspaces;
*/

    @Column(length = 1, columnDefinition ="char")
    private String active;

    @Column(name = "reset_token")
    @JsonIgnore
    private String resetToken;

    @Column(name = "reset_token_time")
    @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss")
    @JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss", timezone = "Asia/Seoul")
    private LocalDateTime resetTokenTime;


    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public Long getOrganization_id() {
        return organization_id;
    }

    public void setOrganization_id(Long organization_id) {
        this.organization_id = organization_id;
    }

    public Organization getOrganization() {
        return organization;
    }

    public void setOrganization(Organization organization) {
        this.organization = organization;
    }

    public List<Role> getRoles() {
        return roles;
    }

    public void setRoles(List<Role> roles) {
        this.roles = roles;
    }

/*  public List<Workspace> getWorkspaces() {
        return workspaces;
    }

    public void setWorkspaces(List<Workspace> workspaces) {
        this.workspaces = workspaces;
    }*/

    public String getActive() {
        return active;
    }

    public void setActive(String active) {
        this.active = active;
    }

    public String getResetToken() {
        return resetToken;
    }

    public void setResetToken(String resetToken) {
        this.resetToken = resetToken;
    }

    public LocalDateTime getResetTokenTime() {
        return resetTokenTime;
    }

    public void setResetTokenTime(LocalDateTime resetTokenTime) {
        this.resetTokenTime = resetTokenTime;
    }
}
```

Comment: Ditch your aspect as it destroys properly calling the method and Spring Security already has support for this out-of-the-box you don't need AOP for that. Use the `@AuthenticationPrincipal` on your method argument.

Comment: I can get only username, password, enabled and etc. through @AuthenticationPrincipal, but there are other params in my User object located in the Model folder.

Comment: If you use your own `User` object that is what you get, you don't have to use the Spring Security `User` object.

Comment: I know there are many ways but don't want the controller to be redundant, so finally chose this - https://stackoverflow.com/a/41327161/7344596

Comment: @GetMapping("/binders")
    public Page<Binder> listBinder(@AuthenticationPrincipal AccessTokenUserInfo accessTokenUserInfo) {

/* Now, don't need this...        
User user = userRepository.findByEmail(accessTokenUserInfo.getUsername()).orElseThrow(() ->
                        new UsernameNotFoundException("Email : " + accessTokenUserInfo.getUsername() + " not found"));*/

       return binderService.findByPage(1, 2, accessTokenUserInfo.getId(), accessTokenUserInfo.getOrganization_id());
    }

Answer (score 0):

Try this, [doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#aop-ataspectj-advice-params-passing):

```
@Around(
"execution(* net.inter.warp.bridge.controller.*.*(..) && " +
"args(authenticatedUser,..)"
```